SpringBoot Hibernate Select returning empty data
We have a SpringBoot application that has multiple tables and we have an issue with the select of one of them.
We have the next CRUD:

Player
Team
Tournament
User

We made a table called tournament-teams that links tournament with teams.
@Entity
@Table(name = "tournamentTeam")
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class TournamentTeam {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer inscriptionId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "team_id")
    private Team team;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "tournament_id")
    private Tournament tournament;

    public TournamentTeam(Team team, Tournament tournament) {
        this.team = team;
        this.tournament = tournament;
    }
}

import com.tournament_wizard.TournamentWizard.entity.TournamentTeam;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface TournamentTeamRepository extends JpaRepository<TournamentTeam, Long> {
}

import com.tournament_wizard.TournamentWizard.entity.TournamentTeam;
import com.tournament_wizard.TournamentWizard.repository.TournamentTeamRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class TournamentTeamService {
    @Autowired
    private TournamentTeamRepository tournamentTeamRepository;

    public List<TournamentTeam> getAllTournamentTeams() {
        return tournamentTeamRepository.findAll();
    }

    public TournamentTeam getTournamentTeamById(Long id) {
        return tournamentTeamRepository.findById(id).orElse(null);
    }

    public TournamentTeam saveOrUpdateTournamentTeam(TournamentTeam tournamentTeam) {
        return tournamentTeamRepository.save(tournamentTeam);
    }

    public void deleteTournamentTeam(Long id) {
        tournamentTeamRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}

import com.tournament_wizard.TournamentWizard.entity.TournamentTeam;
import com.tournament_wizard.TournamentWizard.service.TournamentTeamService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/tournament-teams")
public class TournamentTeamController {
    @Autowired
    private TournamentTeamService tournamentTeamService;

    @GetMapping
    public List<TournamentTeam> getAllTournamentTeams() {
        return tournamentTeamService.getAllTournamentTeams();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public TournamentTeam getTournamentTeamById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return tournamentTeamService.getTournamentTeamById(id);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public TournamentTeam createTournamentTeam(@RequestBody TournamentTeam tournamentTeam) {
        return tournamentTeamService.saveOrUpdateTournamentTeam(tournamentTeam);
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public TournamentTeam updateTournamentTeam(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody TournamentTeam updatedTournamentTeam) {
        TournamentTeam existingTournamentTeam = tournamentTeamService.getTournamentTeamById(id);
        if (existingTournamentTeam != null) {
            existingTournamentTeam.setTeam(updatedTournamentTeam.getTeam());
            existingTournamentTeam.setTournament(updatedTournamentTeam.getTournament());
            return tournamentTeamService.saveOrUpdateTournamentTeam(existingTournamentTeam);
        }
        return null; // Handle error if the tournament team with the given id doesn't exist
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public void deleteTournamentTeam(@PathVariable Long id) {
        tournamentTeamService.deleteTournamentTeam(id);
    }
}

The problem is when we make a call from Postman to this endpoint http://localhost:8080/api/tournament-teams, it returns an empty array or null.
We checked that the database on MySQL workbench was not empty or null.
We tried to fix this by rebuilding the CRUD and asking many AI's about the error but none of them resolve anything.
We expected that the return is the database data and not an empty or null array.

Set org.hibernate.SQL to DEBUG and post result (Sorry, sure if you use hibernate)

here you go @WladimirDiskowski
2024-04-03T15:02:53.397+02:00 DEBUG 14260 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select tt1_0.inscription_id,tt1_0.team_id,tt1_0.tournament_id from tournament_team tt1_0
Hibernate: select tt1_0.inscription_id,tt1_0.team_id,tt1_0.tournament_id from tournament_team tt1_0

Perfect. Can you please also set org.springframework.web to DEBUG and org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql to TRACE

thanks for everything you are doing @WladimirDiskowski there is the code you requested:
2024-04-04T17:22:04.212+02:00 DEBUG 28996 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/api/tournament-teams", parameters={} 2024-04-04T17:22:04.213+02:00 DEBUG 28996 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.tournament_wizard.TournamentWizard.controller.TournamentTeamController#getAllTournamentTeams() 2024-04-04T17:22:04.219+02:00 DEBUG 28996 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select

tt1_0.inscription_id,tt1_0.team_id,tt1_0.tournament_id from tournament_team tt1_0 Hibernate: select tt1_0.inscription_id,tt1_0.team_id,tt1_0.tournament_id from tournament_team tt1_0 2024-04-04T17:22:04.225+02:00 DEBUG 28996 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Using 'application/json', given [application/json] and supported [application/json, application/*+json] 2024-04-04T17:22:04.225+02:00 DEBUG 28996 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Writing [[]] 2024-0

Application can't find values in Database.

Application can't find values in Database. You have to 1) Execute Statement select tt1_0.inscription_id,tt1_0.team_id,tt1_0.tournament_id from tournament_team tt1_0 on your Database 2) If Result ist emty - this is  the cause why you have empty response 3) If Result is not empty then Application conects with other Database as you mean. Check your datasource configuration. 3a) If you use Hikari pool set     com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig to DEBUG
